# what is the purpose of support files in MySQL?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have installed MySQL 5.6.17 on my Ubuntu 14.04 following the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-installation.html.

The instructions says to use the optional command :

```
shell> cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

But I do not see any "my-medium.cnf" file in the folder.

The instructions also mentions :

```
shell> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

What exactly is the purpose of copying this file to the destination?

Comment: You are reading old documentation. Switch to the version of documentation that matches the version of MySQL you are running. Those files were removed some time ago.

Comment: 2 things.... 1) you are reading MySQL 5.0 docs, but installing 5.6. and 2) is there some reason you don't just install it using Ubuntu's packaging system? Doing it the way you are now will quickly leave you vulnerable to security issues unless you are going to be very diligent at patching. See https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/mysql.html

Comment: You guys are absolutely right. I was looking at an older version of the installation instructions. I have gone through the right one at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-installation.html and it looks exactly the same, except that the "my-medium.cnf" line has been removed. So that answers my first question. Thanks!

Comment: @ThatGraemeGuy I downloaded the Debian Linux version from the site but Ubuntu software Center gave me a warning while installing "The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath.". So i downloaded the generic linux version and installed it manually.

Comment: You did it wrong then. Read the link I posted from the Ubuntu site.

Comment: Thanks, i had gone through the link. I did try apt-get initially but it was downloading the 5.5 MySql version, while i wanted the latest 5.6 version. So had to cancel it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .cnf file is the MySQL configuration file from which mysql reads it's configuration.

The mysql.server file is the script that is used to control the mysq service.

Comment: the first part of my question is answered in the comments under the question. The second part of my question was meant to understand the purpose of copying it to the init.d folder. If i don't want the MySql server to start automatically on system start, can i skip this step?

Comment: Most people would expect the startup script to be in /etc/init.d. Most distros have a way of enabling/disabling startup scripts without having to remove them from /etc/init.d

Comment: Since i use the mysqld_safe command to manually start the MySql server, I don't really need the mysql.server script. So i am not copying it to the init.d folder in the first place. Thanks!